# What Drupal modules are required for this rotating images effect?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

For example: http://www.elegantthemes.com/preview/SimplePress/

Assume there are four CCK nodes, in each stores one image and body text. Which module is needed for the rotating image effect? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with views this will do the trick: http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow